Does the "EMI capacitor" in an isolated SMPS present an additional capacitive load for the primary side switches?
I have recently received an answer to another question (that answer is now deleted unfortunately), for which I would like some clarification. Namely, it described a particular case of isolated SMPS (e.g. full-bridge converter) that uses top-side FETs. The way I imagine the described circuit is exemplarily shown below.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
According to my understanding, the text further suggested that the presence of the top-side FETs (and their isolated drivers) puts the capacitor Ciso effectively in parallel to the primary-secondary capacitance of the transformer. That would then highly disfavor large values of capacitor Ciso, because it would present a huge transient load to the switch FETs.
I would like to understand this reasoning. My assumption is that Ciso is always in series with the transformer's parasitic isolation capacitance, as far as common-mode switch noise is concerned. Namely, I think it is even in the circuit for precisely this reason, to return the common-mode switch noise to the primary side.
What is the concrete topological requirement that makes Ciso:

appear in parallel to the transformer's isolation capacitance for common-mode switch noise? If present, where would the return current flow?
present a load for the primary side switch FETs?


You have confused which Ciso's are which; there are others.
If you expand your diagram out further, you will find two additional isolation barriers -- assuming isolated high-side gate drivers are used, which was the context of the answer in question.
For a more concrete representation, consider this complete schematic: 
https://www.seventransistorlabs.com/Images/Diode_Recovery_Tester.pdf (links to my site -- own work)

As a complete realized schematic, this is obviously quite a lot busier than needed, but it allows me to point out everything in play.
First, consider the bottom-right corner.  Q4 is a high-side switch, into a load attached to the terminal block P2.  I have drawn these connections in red: an inductor and diode are attached at this location, giving a sort of buck converter topology with a short-circuited output.  Thus, when Q4 switches on, current builds linearly in the inductor, and when it turns off, the diode "catches" that current.  Measurements are made around the diode (current shunt resistor, voltage probe).
This buck converter is built on the reference ground, i.e., the DC link bypass, and diode and inductor, are all common with the low-voltage section.
Note that I have drawn the switch node as a named ground GD0V.  This connects to the gate drive supply, a simple DC-DC converter using a MAX253 push-pull driver into a center-tapped transformer.  The stray capacitance of this transformer is indicated, and notice it goes between the reference ground and the driver local ground GD0V, which is actually the switching node.
Thus, full switching voltage is applied across this isolation barrier.
This is completely separate from the mains isolation barrier in an AC-DC power supply, the Ciso in your figure.
The stray C in the above figure, is its own separate "Ciso" in context of the gate drive DC-DC converter, between those grounds, and unrelated to the primary-to-secondary isolation.
For further illustration, consider the layout of this circuit:

Original: https://www.seventransistorlabs.com/Images/Diode_Recovery_Tester.jpg
As you can see, GD0V is truly a local reference plane for the gate drive circuit; it just happens to be flying on the switch node above the surrounding (low voltage reference) plane.  This is maybe kind of echoed in the schematic, the gate drive section being drawn as a tight block between rails.
If this were part of an off-line power supply, there would be -- well the inverter section would be a little different of course -- but importantly, there would be an isolation transformer connected off the right side, and all the secondary-side stuff.
Putting an excessive capacitor across the driver DC-DC's "stray C" would needlessly couple the switching node to the surrounding circuit, worsening CMRR of the driver (i.e., putting more voltage drop across the GD0V link over to Q4).
Putting an excessive capacitor across the (imagined) mains isolation transformer might not be problematic in and of itself, but the common-mode impedance thus introduced can be problematic: as above, when high AC voltage as well must be isolated, when low current is required (as for mains ground leakage), or when common-mode rejection is required (compare to Ethernet signaling, which uses center-tapped transformers to balance CM currents into an ESD shunt capacitor, and CMCs to reject EMI).
Another more qualitative argument, is not to use more than is needed.  If Ciso is say 100pF, then using much more than some nF will have little further impact on the attenuation.  In an ideal case, attenuation is simply the ratio of capacitances; however in a real EMC context, the stray inductance of the path (particularly the capacitor's body, lead and trace length) will dominate at high frequencies, and the capacitor value doesn't particularly matter beyond some margin.
You're also up against the inhomogeneity of the circuit in question: even if constructed on ground planes (like the above pictured example, but suppose the two planes were primary and secondary of an off-line isolated supply), there can be voltage drop across the planes which drives common-mode into the connectors -- because the input and output connectors, and Ciso, are not (in general) in the same physical location, and thus pick up different voltages across the planes.
Conveniently, this limiting practical value is some nF for most SMPS applications, so we can meet ground leakage requirements fairly easily.  (This is harder for medical grade SMPS, where some 100s pF might be tolerable and so the Ciso cannot be so easily swamped, and more CMCs must be used to achieve the required attenuation.)
My formative / illustrative example of this, was testing a simple 200W flyback power supply I had designed and built.  I put in all likely positions of 'Y' capacitors on the layout (earth to mains H/N, earth to pre-CMC, primary DC- to secondary DC-, earth to secondary, etc.), and tested various combinations of those capacitors (just poking a capacitor into the empty PTH pads... very carefully I might add, as this was live(!)).  Transformer capacitance was probably on the order of 100pF, and it was clear that for much more than 1nF, further gains were inconsequential; going from 1 to 2.2nF, in most locations where benefit was found, saw a few dB further improvement, but compared to the 20dB+ effect of the capacitor being there at all, it's not really much, is it?  (1nF / 2.2nF is a 6.8dBV change: evidently, other effects/strays were in play.)  Whereas adding another CMC and small Y cap might contribute another 20-40dB, a much more meaningful improvement.

Thank you for clearing my confusion. So the Ciso acts as a capacitive load, not for the switches driving the transformer bridging this respective gap (MAX253 in your case), but for external switches, which make the voltage across the isolation fly up and down (Q4 and buck diode in your case). The latter aren't shown in my schematic, but I realize now, what/where they would be, if my drawn schematic was itself an isolated power supply for a high-side FET.
